# ASP.NET C# ImageButton OnClick Event Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Somehow this `OnClick` event is not being triggered with click. Code behind is working if being put into button click or linkbutton click. Only `ImageButton` is not working.

Usually when I hover over a button/linkbutton I can see something like 'dopostback xxxxx' at the left bottom of my browser. For this imagebutton nothing is showing. Also if I put break in the debugger for MapClick, the break is not triggered.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.5267385,-0.0816741&zoom=13&size=288x280&markers=color:red%7Csize:mid%7C51.5267385,-0.0816741&key=AIzaSyBXJgX6ArIDh8UfwdGQK-wAoU_eCJmSTXs" 
     OnClick="MapClick" CausesValidation="false" />
```

```cs
protected void MapClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string mytext = Session["CurrentSalonName"].ToString().Replace(' ', '+') + "+" + Session["CurrentSalonAddress"].ToString().Replace(' ', '+');
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://maps.google.com/?q=" + mytext +"');", true);
        }
```

```
<section class="directory_listiing_detail_area single_area section-bg section-padding-strict" style="padding-top: 30px">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
                    <div class="widget atbd_widget widget-card">
                        <div class="widget-body atbdb_content_module_contents">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.5267385,-0.0816741&zoom=13&size=288x280&markers=color:red%7Csize:mid%7C51.5267385,-0.0816741&key=AIzaSyBXJgX6ArIDh8UfwdGQK-wAoU_eCJmSTXs" OnClick="MapClick" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Comment: Please post the code for `MapClick`.

Comment: Please post the container of the ImageButton

Comment: code for MapClick and containers are posted

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in the browser console?